# WSUS Patch Report Generate Remotly

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-server, windows-update

I have a PowerShell script ready with me to generate Windows patch report based on the IP/hostname from WSUS. But in this case, the script should have to execute from the WSUS Server itself. I have multiple WSUS Server available in multiple locations. Is there any way to execute my script remotely from a centralised server and get the patch information.

> ```
> [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
> $wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($WSUSTargetHostName,$False,8530)
> ```

Above is the way that I used to connect to WSUS Server. But this only works from inside the WSUS Server.

Can someone suggest any new methods or way achieve this?

Comment: If I understand your situation then from a central location you can Invoke-Command that code on a remote WSUS server.

Comment: @EBGreen Will this Invoke-Command have administrator privilege to run the script

Comment: If you go look at the Get-Help for Invoke-Command you will see that you can specify credentials when you call it. So whether or not it has admin rights is up to you.